# Play the video only in the active slide in splidejs Slider

Tags: javascript

I am using Splide https://splidejs.com/ with the video extension to make a video gallery. I set it to show more than one slide and the active slide is centered.
but all other visible slides also get a play button and could be played, I don't want that. I want only the active slide in the middle to play the video, all other slides must be scrolled to be active.
Can I do this?

Comment: Seems there Splide video extensions. https://splidejs.com/extension-video/

Comment: As I wrote I already use this extension. But all visible slides can play the video, I only want the centered slide to be active, all other slides must be moved to the center position to become active

Comment: It would be possible if using onclick event for arrow buttons. When moving slides by clicking arrow buttons then videos can be active as changing video.controls to true or false.

Comment: But because of using the library setting click event is not possible.